# Applying 3D Transform After Pinching It

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to Apply 3D transform after scaling image from pinch Gesture Recognizer.. When a 3d Transform is applied The image get rescaled to default size ( i.e size before Pinch) . How can i Stop imageView from going back to the Previous state ( i.e before Pinch )

```
self.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
 self.transform.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;

  self.transform = CATransform3DRotate(self.transform, CGFloat(145 * M_PI / 180), 0, 1, 0)

  viewToDelete.layer.transform = self.transform

  func handlePinch(_ nizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    nizer.view!.transform = nizer.view!.transform.scaledBy(x: nizer.scale, y: nizer.scale)

    nizer.scale = 1
}
```

In the Image Left most view is the created view//.. view next to It is scaled using Pinch... 3rd downside is after 3dTransform
[image: 1st view is new created, 2nd is scaled, 3rd transformed to original]

Comment: The `m34` transform should be set as the superlayer's `sublayerTransform`. Then the rotation should be set as the sublayer's `transform`.

Comment: i am new to CATransform.. can you please include a code Snippet?